# Special Relativity: A showing question $c^2-v^2$ using Velocity transformations

Tags: special-relativity

I have been trying to do this question for ages now:

A particle has a velocity  **v** ={$v_x,v_y,v_z$} in S and a velocity $\bf v'$={$ v'_x, v'_y,v'_z$} in S'. Prove from velocity transformations that

$c^2-v^2 =\frac{c^2(c^2-v'^2)(c^2-V^2)}{(c^2+{Vv'_z})^2}$.

The obvious thing, in my opinion is that we have to use "inverse velocity transformations", basing on the denominator. The particle is moving along the z-axis, and I also know that the invariant line element

$(ds)^2/dt =(cdt/dt)^2-{(dx/dt)^2 +(dy/dt)^2+(dz/dt)^2}$ such that

$(ds/dt)^2=c^2-v^2 =\frac{1}{\gamma^2}$

My opinion is that i must show that

$(cdt/dt)^2-{(dx/dt)^2 +(dy/dt)^2+(dz/dt)^2}$=$\frac{c^2(c^2-v'^2)(c^2-V^2)}{(c^2+{Vv'_z})^2}$.

I have that

$v_z= \frac{v'_z+V}{1+\frac{Vv'_z}{c^2}}$

$v_y=\frac{v'_y}{\gamma(1+\frac{Vv'_z}{c^2})}$

$v_x=\frac{v'_x}{\gamma(1+\frac{Vv'_z}{c^2})}$

Comment: What is $V$? And what is the relation between $S$ and $S'$?

Comment: V is not given explicitly in the question. This is all there is...I assume that it is the one we have in the velocity transformations. And I think the relationship between $S$ and $S'$ is deduced from there as well.

Comment: I initially made an error. i have verified everything about the question now.

Comment: Its been to long for me since I did these things. You can also post it on physics stack exchange, I think you have more chance there.

Comment: Thank you @Jens . I have done so now.